# Access function from a different module in rust

Tags: rust

If I have the following:

```text
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── main
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
├── module2
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       ├── lib.rs
│       └── builder.rs
```

Where the `Cargo.toml` file in the root is the following:

```toml
[workspace]

members = [
    "main",
]
```

I want to access a function from `builder.rs` in main when testing(i.e. `cfg(test)`), how can I do so?

Module2 is a library(it was created by running `cargo new module2 --lib`.

I tried the following:

```rust
// module2/builder.rs

pub fn build() { /*...*/ }
```

```rust
// module2/lib.rs

#[cfg(test)]
mod mock;

#[cfg(test)]
pub use mock::build;
```

```toml
// main/Cargo.toml
// ...
[dependencies]
module2 = { path = "../module2" }
```

```rust
// main.rs

#[cfg(test)]
use module2::build;

/*
...
*/
```

This doesn't work and I get the following error:

```text
error[E0432]: unresolved import `module2::build`
 --> main/src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use module2::build;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `build` in the root
```

Comment: `module2` is not in your workspace; is this intentional?

Comment: Please paste the full error here.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, it doesn't make any difference if it was in my workspace.

Comment: It should not, but this looks like a mistake so I asked.

Comment: I have pasted the full error now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` of `module1` is not `test` of `main`: each crate gets `cfg(test)` turned on only when it itself is being tested, not when a dependency of it is being tested.

You can use `cfg(debug_assertions)` as an approximation or a custom feature.